# Reading content and children from an XML tag in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml tree, where I have a tag

```
<et>
Middle English (Scots)
<it>polit</it>
, Latin
<it>politus,</it>
from past participle of
<it>polire</it>
</et>
```

I want to read the content of et, and put the words in `<it>` in italics. 
But I can only read direct text inside et and not children. PHP Code

Comment: please provide your PHP code

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about programing,  So you need to provide your php code and tell us what result your code is giving you,

Comment: SimpleXML doesn't cater well for this kind of content - it assumes an element either has text content or children, not both - so I think you'll have to use a more in-depth XML API, like [DOM](http://php.net/dom), which lets you access "text nodes" individually. However, as Rohit Gupta, there is not enough here to make a good question for this site. Check out the [ask] help page.

Answer (score 0):

This puts the words in `<it>` into $itArray:

```
$myXMLData =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<et>
Middle English (Scots)
<it>polit</it>
, Latin
<it>politus,</it>
from past participle of
<it>polire</it>
</et>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$itArray = array();
foreach($xml->it as $it){
    array_push($itArray, $it);
}
print($itArray[0]); // polit
print($itArray[1]); // politus
print($itArray[2]); // polire
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with `<et>`, but this prints out all of `<et>` content:

```
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement($myXMLData);
$xml->asXML();  
print($xml);
```

EDIT: I'll assume you'll want to put the content in `<et>` in an array as well. Since the XML is so messed up, you'll have to use regex.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: "Since the XML is so messed up, you'll have to use regex." Good grief, no! You just need a more in-depth XML API, like [DOM](http://php.net/dom).